# Replacing characters in Scrapy item

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape from a commerce website using Scrapy. For the price tag, I want to remove the "$", but my current code does not work.

```
  def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//section[@class="items-box"]'):
      item = ShopItem()
      item['name'] = sel.xpath('a/div/h3/text()').extract()
      item['price'] = sel.xpath('a/div/div/div[1]/text()').extract().replace("$", "")
      yield item

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

What is the appropriate method to remove characters when using Scrapy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`extract()` would return you a *list*, you can use `extract_first()` to get a single value:

```
item['price'] = sel.xpath('a/div/div/div[1]/text()').extract_first().replace("$", "")
```

Or, you can use the [`.re()` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions), something like:

```
item['price'] = sel.xpath('a/div/div/div[1]/text()').re(r"\$(.*?)")
```

Comment: Thank for this! Is there anyway I can use this with `extract()`?

Comment: @Maverick sure, `.re()` actually acts as "extract()" replacement in this case. What is your specific use case?

Comment: ahh I see. I have 3 I am currently working on: 1) `response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/section[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/p/text()').extract_first().replace(" per week", "")`                                             
             2) `response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/section[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/label/text()').extract_first().replace("\n","")`                                                    
     3) `response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/section[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/p/text()').extract_first().replace("Guide total - ", "")`

Comment: @Maverick you can do `.re_first()` btw.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe - I'll have a little play with them and see how I get on!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join()` first and then `replace()`
to convert the list into a string and replacing `"$"` with `""`

Example:

```
prices = ''.join(price)
if '$' in prices:
    prices = prices.replace("$", "")
```

Hopefully, it helps...